# C# Find substring based on input string

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm new to C# so I have not much experience.

For a simple experience project I need to find keywords from a sentence which resemble the input I get.

It now seems that the solutions is way more complex than I thought it would be, so please forgive my lack of experience or knowledge.

I am getting a string from my database which can have any number of letters and the rest of the string are figures, but the total number of characters from the string must be used for the matching.

```
string ThisIsTheTemplateToLookFor = "AB12345678"
```

And I've got a string with some text:

```
string FromThisStringINeedToFind = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s and here comes the text to find AB54925871";
```

With `ThisIsTheTemplateToLookFor` probably a regex command must be build to find similar pieces of text.

So it needs to find:

```
AB12345678
AB87654321
AB67812345
...
etc
...
```

The regex must look for the two letters and 8 figures from the sample string.
Or in a different situation the `ThisIsTheTemplateToLookFor` string could be `A1234` the regex should find `A1234`, `A4321`, `A3910`, etc.

Or as Tim Schmelter suggested maybe a Levenshtein Distance Algorithm

Sorry for the language as I'm not native English speaking

I think his point is that the search string is different in subtle and as yet not enumerated ways than the string that should be found. In the example, the search string is `AB12345678`, but the string that should get discovered is `AB54925871`.

My guess is if the search string is `AB12345678`, then any 10 character substring containing those 10 characters in any order should be found. –  hatchet

- In the first example AB and any 8 figures should give a result.
- In the second example A and any 4 figures should give a result.

Comment: Instead of asking a new question you should edit [your old](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815680/use-a-string-to-find-a-simular-out-of-a-large-string-with-regex) so that it will be reopened.

Comment: Care to clarify? I can't understand what you're asking... Provide more samples of inputs and outputs for your program.

Comment: Hi @Tim, I do not know how, and your responce has been removed, So I'm a little stuck here.

Comment: @user3058288: just click the edit-link below your question.   However, aapparently it' still not that clear.

Comment: Hi Tim, I'm really trying to be as informative as possible, but I don't know how to explain more as technical english is not something I grew up with.

I have a variable which I want to use to find simular text.
Maybe see it as a Phone number, which can be diffrent for diffrent persons.
I want to use the way a Phone number is writen to search for Phone numbers in a sentence.
But instead of it being a Phone numer it is a piece of text starting with a letter (or more) and the rest are figures.

Comment: @user3058288: it's unclear because of sentences like "_My guess is if...._" which suggest that you don't know the requirement yourself ;) Edit the other question with a meaningful sample and with clear rules. If i understood you right you want to find **words** in a sentence that have 1.) the same number of characters 2.) start with the same number of letters 3.) have the same number of following digits.

Comment: @Tim, that is text from a comment the user Hatchet had placed in the other thread.
It was not my text.
And he was quite right about what I am trying to do.
And so are you, you now understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @user3058288: then it contradicts with your own explanation. Hatchet: _"any 10 character substring containing those 10 characters in any order"_ You: _"must look for the two letters and 8 figures from the sample string"_ Also, is it important that the two letters are at the beginning and the digits are at the end or can it be the other way round?

Comment: @Tim, I've added your text to the Original post.
How do I get it released?

Comment: @user3058288: you have to wait until people with enough reputation(3000) voted to reopen it. 2 are missing.

Comment: @Tim, Well thank you very much for your assistance, I'll have another look tommorrow than.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have now clarified the requirement in [your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815680/how-can-i-find-a-word-in-a-sentence-that-has-the-same-length-letters-and-digit?lq=1) but i cannot post an answer since it's still closed i'll put my two cents here.

You don't need a regex for this, following works as desired. Your sample:

```
string sample = "AB12345678";
string subject = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s and here comes the text to find AB54925871";
```

Now you want to find words in the sentence with the same `Length`, which Starts with the same letters and end with the same number of (consecutive)digits:

```
string letters = string.Join("", sample.TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter));
int countDigits = sample.SkipWhile(Char.IsLetter).TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).Count();
```

You can use this LINQ query:

```
var matchingWords = subject.Split()  // splits by spaces, tabs and new-lines
    .Where(word => sample.Length == word.Length
        && letters == string.Join("", word.TakeWhile(Char.IsLetter))
        && countDigits == word.SkipWhile(Char.IsLetter).TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).Count());
string word = matchingWords.FirstOrDefault();  // AB54925871
```

If no matching word was found it returns `null`.

If you want to find all and separate them with comma:

```
string allWords = string.Join(",", matchingWords);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I've tried your solution.
And it works like a charm.

But I've got a new situations I found during testing:
It can happen that multiple sample's can be found.
How would I have "var matchingWords" have all hits in a list seprated by ",".
Or do I need to create a new question for this?

Comment: Hi @Tim, I can't accept your answer twice, but thank you very much, as your answers helpped me a lot, to get passed this problem.

Answer (score 0):

From your problem statement, we're not talking rocket science here: just create a little *factory method* like this that does what you want:

```
static Regex CreateRegularExpressionFromTemplate( string template )
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;

  foreach( char c in template )
  {
    if      ( char.IsLetter(      c ) ) sb.Append( @"\p{L}" ) ;
    else if ( char.IsNumber(      c ) ) sb.Append( @"\d"    ) ;
    else if ( char.IsWhiteSpace(  c ) ) sb.Append( @"\s"    ) ;
    else if ( char.IsPunctuation( c ) ) sb.Append( @"\p{P}" ) ;
    else throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("template") ;
  }

  string pattern = sb.ToString() ;
  Regex rx = new Regex( pattern ) ;
  return rx ;
}
```

Which will turn this

```
@"AB12345678"
```

into this

```
@"\p{L}\p{L}\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d"
```

Then you can do things like

```
Regex rx = CreateRegularExpressionFromTemplate( "AB12345678" ) ;
Match m  = rx.Match( "This is zX98320987 speaking." ) ;

if ( m.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine( "We matched '{0}'" , m.Value ) ;
}
else
{
  Console.WriteLine( "no match found" ) ;
}
```

And get the expected

```
We matched 'zX98320987'
```

**Edited To Note:** If you need to match on a word boundary, you can simply add the appropriate positive look-behind and positive look-ahead assertions:

```
static Regex CreateRegularExpressionFromTemplate( string template )
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;

  sb.Append( @"(?<=(^|\W))" ) ; // require the match to at the beginning of a word
  foreach( char c in template )
  {
    if      ( char.IsLetter(      c ) ) sb.Append( @"\p{L}" ) ;
    else if ( char.IsNumber(      c ) ) sb.Append( @"\d"    ) ;
    else if ( char.IsWhiteSpace(  c ) ) sb.Append( @"\s"    ) ;
    else if ( char.IsPunctuation( c ) ) sb.Append( @"\p{P}" ) ;
    else throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("template") ;
  }
  sb.Append( @"(?=($|\W))" ; // require the match to end at the end of a word

  string pattern = sb.ToString() ;
  Regex rx = new Regex( pattern ) ;
  return rx ;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but first matched result is not the result I needed.
It would have if zX98320987 was AB98320987

Now as I'm just begining to learn, I can't oversee what the additional code does.
But an you explain a bit in layman's terms?